# How to crop responsive image in website

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've got an image currently positioned in website HTML. Its responsive
by using bootstrap - its width reduce properly when i check it in
different devices. However in this particular case i want it crop to
left and right when you enlarge the picture.

I've tried many techniques but none of them is working for me. Could
it be because i am using bootstrap responsive function? or am i doing
something wrong.

I'd love to get some help. Also currently this is the code i'm using:

```
   <section>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 woodbar">
          <img src="img/WoodenBar2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
         </div>
           </div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

CSS is clean for now since bootstrap has img-responsive built in.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Enlarge it how? Oh...and cropping is fundamentally oppposed to responsiveness. You have to pick one or the other.

Comment: Maybe position two graphics so that they partially overlap, so when the lower-layer graphic expands, more of it is covered up.

Comment: Perhaps i've been unclear. I'd like the img i have to reduce in size until a certain size (aka responsive). From a preticular size downward(lets say 980px) i want it to start cropping the image from left and right.

Basically its an image of an wooden bar with flags int he middle. When viewed through phone all the users should see is the flags eventually.

Comment: check picturefill for responsive images..https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and i'd like to stick wit hthat. Any other solution perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using translate on the image, to crop it.

```css
* {
  margin : 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#imgContainer {
  overflow    : hidden;
  width       : 100vh;/*this will need to be changed manually*/
  height      : 100vh;/*this will need to be changed manually*/
  margin-left : calc(50vw - 50vh);/*this will need to be changed manually*/
}
img#toCrop {
  margin-top  : -20vh;/*this will need to be changed manually*/
  margin-left : -30vh;/*this will need to be changed manually*/
  width       : 140vh;/*this will need to be changed manually*/
  height      : 140vh;/*this will need to be changed manually*/
}
@media only screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {/*this will need to be changed manually*/
  #imgContainer {
    width       : 100vw;
    height      : 100vw;
    margin-top  : calc(50vh - 50vw);
    margin-left : 0px;
  }
  img#toCrop {
    margin-top  : -20vw;
    margin-left : -30vw;
    width       : 140vw;
    height      : 140vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id = 'imgContainer'>
  <img id = 'toCrop' src = 'https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff'>
</div>
<!--Will work best as an iframe-->
```

most of it will need to be changed manually though.

Comment: Please provide an example to the user to make this answer meaningful